# How to restore with multicast 3 systems: Windows 7, Windows 2008 and Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, windows-7, multicast, system-restore

We have used an old version of Norton Ghost to do backups and restores of computers. There are few groups of computers with the same hardware and we have used multicast. We have had Windows XP, Windows 2003 and Fedora Linux on each computer. Unfortunately we have to install Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2. Unfortunately, our version of Norton Ghost doesn't have support for these systems.

The problems

- We need license for about 200 computers.
- We have to do restore once a week.
- We don't have time, hardware, network or hands to do it without multicast.
- We need support for old and new versions of Windows and the common distributions of Linux.
- The initiation of restoring system on client have to start form boot CD.

Well. It looks Fog and Clonezilla need a network boot. New version of Norton Ghost will be probably good enough. I have found there is a proprietary software from Acronis too. Unfortunately, it is probably quite expensive.

Well, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have used Symantec Ghost Solution Suite 2.5 Multicasting to image Windows7 and Server2008 and it got the job done.  I think that that will be your best bet in this instance.

http://www.symantec.com/themes/ghost/index.jsp

*I just burned multiple CDs to boot from, and rarely saw imaging issues with the software.

Answer (score 0):

If you can setup a w2k8r2 server it supports multicast deploymnet.

Comment: Is there a Live CD for W2k8R2 or something? In the worst case we have to be able to restore a whole hard drive.

Comment: darn needed to read you ? better!